# Solving second order ODE with polynomial coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is the solution

Can some one solve this.....

$T.y''+T'y'+T''y=0$., 
where $T$ is a polynomial. Like $1-2x-x^2$ etc. in $x$........

Is there anyway to assume the answer as polynomial and go for substitution or is there any other way?

If I take the first two terms and write it as a product, may be there is a chance. But is there a general procedures for these kind of questions

Comment: Too bad that middle term doesn't have a coefficient of 2.

Comment: If there is 2,,, it can be changed into differential of products, yea I noticed

Answer (score 0):

There is not necessarily an elementary solution.  For example, if $T = 1 - 2x - x^2$, the solutions involve some nasty hypergeometric functions.

Comment: What if the polynomial is 1-x^2

Comment: It's essentially the same for any quadratic with distinct roots.

Comment: Is there anyother way.... There are a lot of methods to solve ode. But none comes in to the mind

Comment: A root of $T$ will be a regular singular point.  Try Frobenius's method.

Comment: Is the solution of the expression y'/y where y is dy/dx   is log y, then  I think i have the. Answer

Comment: Also frobenius method do take the solution as a polynomial expression right.. I read about legenders polynomial, it is the same question with polynomial as 1-x^2

Comment: No, the Frobenius method gives you a power series solution, generally not a polynomial.